# jQuery - getting checked items in name array

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/3kwchkf6/1/

```
    $('[name^="item"]').each(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            itemCheckedList.push($(this).attr('name'));        
        }
    });
    console.log(itemCheckedList);
```

Hi it returns ["item[2001]", "item[2090]"]

I want it to return [2001, 2090]

I was thinking that maybe the solution would include regex somehow or serialize somehow? Thanks.

Comment: `+$(this).attr('name').replace(/\D+/g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.substring()`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/30tfvq29/)**

```
$('[name^="item"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        var start = $(this).attr('name').indexOf('[')+1;
        var end = $(this).attr('name').indexOf(']');
        itemCheckedList.push($(this).attr('name').substring(start, end));        
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Not 100% on your selector without seeing HTML, but the logic to verify if checked and push value into an array is below.

```
if (this.checked)
{
   itemCheckedList.push($(this).val());
}
```

That should work for you.

Comment: it returns ["on","on"]